# Axios asynchronous get requests come back in the wrong order

Tags: javascript

I'm currently trying to use a .each and then making my request inside of it but then when I console.log it, it's not in order. I'm super new to Axios and cheerio and coding in general so I was wondering how I could make the call output come back in order.

```
const axios = require('axios')
const cheerio = require('cheerio')


axios.get('http://www.mangapanda.com/one-piece/1')
    .then((response) => {
        const $ = cheerio.load(response.data)
        //console.log($('option'))
        $('option').each((index, element) => {
            console.log(index)
            axios.get('http://www.mangapanda.com/one-piece/1/'+(index+1)).then((response) => {
                const z = cheerio.load(response.data)
                var x = z('img#img')[0].attribs.src
                console.log(x, index)
            })
        });
    })
```

Comment: Do you just want to get the output in the right order, or do you require the request to happen sequentially?

Comment: I want the output to be in the correct order

Comment: In that case, collect your promises in an array (instead of attaching `.then` on them individually) and call `Promise.all`, like demonstrated below by Quentin.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot I got what I wanted working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of asynchronous functions is that they are done when they are done.

If you need to preserve order, then wrap the promises return by axios in an array and pass it to `Promise.all`.

```
const promises = [
    axios(...),
    axios(...),
    axios(...),
];
Promise.all(promises).then(ordered_array => {
    ordered_array.forEach( result => { ... } );
});
```